# Неочевидное поведение стандартного аллокатора

Tags: c++, heap, выделение-памяти

Решил провести тест стандартного аллокатора памяти кучи. Для этого объявил 3 структуры — с 3, 4 и 5 полями типа int. Выделяю и удаляю память в цикле для каждой из структур и меряю затраченное время.

Результаты получаются несколько неожиданными: для структуры из 3 полей аллокация/деаллокация значительно **медленнее**, чем для 4 и 5, а для структуры из 5 полей — немного **быстрее**, чем для 4. Почему так происходит? Почему не 3<4<5? Почему 5<4?

Использовал gcc в Release режиме (O3), Linux x64.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>


struct A {
    int a, b, c;
};

struct B {
    int a, b, c, d;
};

struct C {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
};


int main() {
    const std::size_t steps = 100000000;

    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        const auto ptr = new A{};
        delete ptr;
    }

    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << '\n' << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << '\n';

    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        const auto ptr = new B{};
        delete ptr;
    }

    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << '\n' << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << '\n';

    start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        const auto ptr = new C{};
        delete ptr;
    }

    end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << '\n' << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Приведите результаты. [На вскидку заметных отличий не наблюдается](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DfPdec2bQHKclGdy)

Comment: @VTT они каждый раз немного отличаются, но тенденция 5<4<3 сохраняется. Вот, например, только что: 1248256355,1205013235,1201574554

Comment: @VTT да, по ссылке тоже 5<4<3

Comment: Вы пишите *"значительно медленнее"* и "*немного быстрее*" - а по факту незначительное различие во втором или третьем разряде...

Comment: @VTT ну, "значительно" и "немного" - понятия относительные. Значительная разница между 3 и 4,5 по сравнению с незначительной разницей между 4 и 5. Я это имел в виду

Comment: Бенчмарки в многозадачной среде и число в 3-тьем знаке - сомнительно. Могу от себя добавить, что если у вас соблюдается выравнивание по "границам 64 байт" то "три int" будет медлененее чем "четыре int" (из за невырованяного обращения)

Comment: Ну нет, по вашим собственным результатам отличие от силы ~4%, по результатам на онлайн прогоне ~1%. Это вообще ни о чем.

Comment: @VTT заметил, что на онлайн тесте стоит O2, а не O3, как у меня. Как по мне, стабильный порядок 5<4<3 для 4% нельзя списать на погрешность

Answer (score 2):

Ваш код тестирует не только производительность аллокатора, но еще и производительность "обнулятеля", работающего после аллокатора, ибо вы указали инициализатор `{}`.

В первом случае при `-O3` GCC делает обнуление через

```
mov     QWORD PTR [rax], 0
mov     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 0
```

Во втором через

```
pxor    xmm0, xmm0
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
```

В третьем

```
pxor    xmm0, xmm0
mov     DWORD PTR [rax+16], 0
movups  XMMWORD PTR [rax], xmm0
```

Это вполне объясняет заметное отставание первого варианта. А уж незначительная победа третьего над вторым (несмотря на дополнительную инструкцию в обнулении) может объясняться всякими дребезгами внутри аллокатора.

Уберите инициализатор `{}`, если вы хотите тестировать именно и только аллокатор.

Answer (score 2):

Код для тестирования страдает от копипасты и может быть радикально сокращен. А помимо собственно аллокации памяти тестируется создание новых объектов, причем в манере, потенциально порождающей исключения. Этого можно избежать, вызвав непосредственно функцию выделения памяти с `::std::nothrow`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    for(auto const allocation_size: {4, 12, 16, 20})
    {
        auto const start{::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        for(auto iteration{100000000}; iteration; --iteration)
        {
            auto const ptr{::operator new(allocation_size, ::std::nothrow)};
            ::operator delete(ptr, ::std::nothrow);
        }
        auto const finish{::std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()};
        ::std::cout << ::std::chrono::duration_cast<::std::chrono::milliseconds>(finish - start).count() << "ms\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/d1byDOfGVvklqFDS)

Примеры результатов (с сервера):

```
4377ms
4357ms
4409ms
4602ms
```

Примеры результатов (c десктопа):

```
5227ms
5138ms
5095ms
5032ms
```

Почему же возникают флуктуации? Во-первых современные процессоры имеют хитрые режимы энергосбережения / авторазгона, динамически меняя свою частоту в разы. Во-вторых в многозадачной среде поток может непредсказуемо вытесняться другими задачами и / или переназначаться на другие ядра процессора. Для чистоты эксперимента стоило бы проводить его на компьютере с фиксированной частотой процессора, с привязкой потока к ядру и без посторонней нагрузки. Тогда бы (возможно) начали проявляться какие-то ньюансы при выделении блоков разного размера. А так различия в 1%, 5% или даже 10% ни говорят ни о чем.

Answer (score 0):

Во первых учитесь не повторять код. Например(хотябы) так:

```
template < class T >
void make_sure(const size_t steps = 1000000)
{
    auto start_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < steps; ++i) {
        const auto ptr = new T;
        delete ptr;
    }

    auto end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << '\n'
         << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time - start_time).count()
         << '\n';
}
```

Дальше легче выполнять проверки. Просто вызовите функцию для разных типов, с разной последовательностью, и вы убедитесь, что быстродействие распрделения не зависит от разницы размера на несколько байт:

```
make_sure<A>();
make_sure<B>();
make_sure<C>();

make_sure<C>();
make_sure<A>();
make_sure<B>();

make_sure<B>();
make_sure<A>();
make_sure<C>();
```

Работает целая программа(препроцессор, линковщик, компилятор...). Пара процетов разницы в наносекундах это также ничто, как и погрешность в детальях производимым высококачественным станком.